# Want to know about SounManager Player ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

I am using bar-ui js of soundmanager.

```
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/bar-ui/
```

I have many players so i don't know about soundid what i want to when page load player should load.

```
http://support.simplepodcaster.com/auto-timestamps/
```

See i have three player on my page i want ....

I tried that

```
var mySoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
id: 'mySound',
url: '/audio/mysoundfile.mp3',
// optional sound parameters here, see Sound Properties for full list
volume: 50,
autoPlay: true,
whileloading: function() {
        jQuery(".playercontent").data('sound-id', this.id);
}
});
```

But the problem i can get sound-id until i play otherwise i did not able to get id.

Is there any way to get id when page load ??

Comment: I don't know about this media player in particular, but is it possible you need to wait until the metadata for the audio file has been downloaded before you can access the ID?

Comment: could you put `console.log(this.id)` right after this line: `whileloading: function() {` and tell us what it shows

Comment: Okay just done it

Comment: I just put it on there http://support.simplepodcaster.com/clammr-it-sample/ but still not getting anything in console :( https://prnt.sc/j9uult  view-source:http://support.simplepodcaster.com/wp-content/plugins/simple-podcast-press/responsive_audio_player/js/bar-ui.js?ver=4.9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `createSound()` it can generate an id, or be assigned one (as you do now).

In the example you paste, you provide an id, so you are overriding the creation of it from soundmanager. That is your sound will have the `id='mySound'`. Following the [docs](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#soundmanager-createsound) you can see what I write here.

Instead, if you create the sound (or player in your case) you could set an id for each sound, by, for example, creating a hash with the name or url of the mp3 track of that player (*so, you can find your sound later by an id you can generate*)

Something like this:

```
var url='/audio/mysoundfile.mp3';
var id=md5(url); // hash it here

var mySoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
   id: id,
   url: url,
   // optional sound parameters here, see Sound Properties for full list
   volume: 50,
   autoPlay: true
   //whileloading: function() {
        //jQuery(".playercontent").data('sound-id', this.id);
   //}
});

jQuery(".playercontent").data('sound-id', id);
```

Or simply obtain an id as follows:

```
var mySoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
   url: '/audio/mysoundfile.mp3',
   // optional sound parameters here, see Sound Properties for full list
   volume: 50,
   autoPlay: true,
   // whileloading: function() {
      // jQuery(".playercontent").data('sound-id', this.id);
   // }
});

console.log(mySoundObject.id);
jQuery(".playercontent").data('sound-id', mySoundObject.id);
```

For both cases, you can use the following method to grab any sound/player you created in your site [directly](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#soundmanager-getsoundbyid):

```
var track='/audio/mysoundfile.mp3';
var id= md5(track);
var mySoundObject = soundManager.getSoundById(id);
```

From other side, there are callbacks you can use like `setVolume()` or force the mp3 file to load (*any method in the SMSound object has the* `this.id` *field available in context*).

But, **it is not really necessary** to use things like that in order to just get the id of your sound/player.

Maybe with this info you could better organize players on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after Evhz help me above i got it.

But he did not post `md5() function`

So What i did in `bar-ui.js`

at line number 168

```
 function makeSound(url) {

      var sound = soundManager.createSound({

       url: url,
```

Changed with this code

```
 function makeSound(url) {

     var soundid = md5(url);
     var getsound = window.soundManager.getSoundById(soundid);

    if (typeof getsound == 'undefined') {
         soundid = md5(url);    
    }else{
         soundid = soundid + 'n';
    }


      var sound = soundManager.createSound({

        url: url,

        id: soundid,
```

and here is md5 function

```
function md5 ( str ) {

    var RotateLeft = function(lValue, iShiftBits) {
            return (lValue<<iShiftBits) | (lValue>>>(32-iShiftBits));
        };

    var AddUnsigned = function(lX,lY) {
            var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
            lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
            lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
            lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
            lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
            lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
            if (lX4 & lY4) {
                return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            }
            if (lX4 | lY4) {
                if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
                    return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                } else {
                    return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                }
            } else {
                return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            }
        };

    var F = function(x,y,z) { return (x & y) | ((~x) & z); };
    var G = function(x,y,z) { return (x & z) | (y & (~z)); };
    var H = function(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); };
    var I = function(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); };

    var FF = function(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
            a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
            return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
        };

    var GG = function(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
            a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
            return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
        };

    var HH = function(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
            a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
            return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
        };

    var II = function(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
            a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
            return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
        };

    var ConvertToWordArray = function(str) {
            var lWordCount;
            var lMessageLength = str.length;
            var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
            var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
            var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
            var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
            var lBytePosition = 0;
            var lByteCount = 0;
            while ( lByteCount < lMessageLength ) {
                lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
                lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
                lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (str.charCodeAt(lByteCount)<<lBytePosition));
                lByteCount++;
            }
            lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
            lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
            lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80<<lBytePosition);
            lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength<<3;
            lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength>>>29;
            return lWordArray;
        };

    var WordToHex = function(lValue) {
            var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
            for (lCount = 0;lCount<=3;lCount++) {
                lByte = (lValue>>>(lCount*8)) & 255;
                WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
                WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
            }
            return WordToHexValue;
        };

    var x=Array();
    var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
    var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
    var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
    var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
    var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;

    x = ConvertToWordArray(str);
    a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;

    for (k=0;k<x.length;k+=16) {
        AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
        a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
        b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
        c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
        d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
    }

    var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);

    return temp.toLowerCase();
}
```

And now i can get soundid from the player html with this code

```
    var soundurl = jQuery( ".playercontent").find('.sm2-playlist-wrapper ul li a').attr('href');
    var Soundid= md5(soundurl);
```